# How to get specific line which has different length in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hello guys i have text file like below and i saved it myfile.txt;

```
!File starts 
Some texts here

version.number = 12345

Some texts here
!File ends
```

And i used a code shown in below to get version number 12345, but sometimes the version number could be 5 or more digit. As an example how can i get 6 digit 123456 with my code.

```
Dim myFile As String
Dim text As String
Dim textline As String
Dim VersionInfo As Integer

Sub DetectModelVersion()

myFile = "C:\test\myfile.txt"

Open myFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    text = text & textline
Loop

Close #1

VersionInfo = InStr(text, "version.number")

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Mid(text, VersionInfo + 17, 6)

End Sub
```

Comment: I would look for the information in the do loop and check if the textline contains "version.number" then do some string manipulation to get from the = to the end of the line.  Then it doesn't matter the length.

Comment: @MichaelRusso yes you're right but could you please help me what is the code of "get from the = to the end of the line".

Answer (score 1):

Just tested the below code and it worked.

```
Option Explicit

Dim myFile As String
Dim text As String
Dim textline As String

Sub DetectModelVersion()

    myFile = "H:\myfile.txt"

    Open myFile For Input As #1

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        If InStr(textline, "version.number") Then
            text = Trim(Mid(textline, InStr(textline, "=") + 1, 255))
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    Close #1

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = text

End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.  I would change from Mid(textline, InStr(textline,"=")+1,255) to Right(textline, Len(textline) - (InStr(textline,"=")+1)) that way the size of the version never matters

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your reply. Also is it possible to trim spaces after the numbers to the end of line (i want to  extract only numbers)

Comment: @MichaelRusso it gives an empty result at me :) do you add this to Scott's code ?

Comment: @Hakan, I just replaced the line in scott's code.  Make sure the 'text = ' portion is still there.  Tested and worked for me.

Comment: @Hakan - I wrapped the text set statement in the `TRIM` function which should clear out white space.

Comment: @MichaelRusso - `Mid(x,y,255)` will also ignore size of version. I assume it will never be more than 255 characters of course, but if it were, than your formula would be better yes.

Comment: It may be prudent to note that VBA's Trim command will only remove spaces from the left and right of a padded string. If it is necessary to remove extraneous spaces from within the string (e.g. two or more spaces between words) then Application.Trim (which mimics the worksheet TRIM function) should be used.